# Cache mechanism not working in android webview load

Tags: android

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}

webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying out exactly, but you can exactly try out this

```
private void saveHtmlFile() {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String fileName = DateFormat.format("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss", System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
        fileName = fileName + ".html";
        File file = new File(path, fileName);
        String html = "<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>This is random text.</body></html>";

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] data = html.getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.close();
            Log.e(TAG, "File Save : " + file.getPath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then,

```
class LoadListener{
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        Log.e("result",html);
    }
}
```

..

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
```

..

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return true;
    }              

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can try this depending on your requirement.!

> https://github.com/dawidsamolyk/Android-Crawler

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But My requirement is that iam working on hybrid application so iam trying to load URL of that.But iam getting All html and js files on every load.So It seems cache is not working